# PHP Comparing two arrays in an conditional statement

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to compare the first with the second array. I have an IF statement and it currently does two checks:

1. It checks to see if there are any rows from my query
2. If the above passes, then I want to traverse the array values of the first array and compare it with the second array. I want to traverse through all the `names` first array (index 0-9) and compare it with the first `name` of the second array (index 0). Keep doing the same thing until we've compared all the indices 0-9 on the first array with all indices 0-9 of the second array.
3. Finally, if there is a match I want to exit my PHP script, else if there is no match I continue to do to stuff.

I have tried using the `in_array()` function and that works, but only with a single variable. Something like this `in_array($firstArray[0], $secondArray)` works. Something like this:

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 && in_array($firstArray[0], $secondArray)){
        exit("exiting now!");
    } 
    else {
        echo "continue to do stuff...";
    }
```

However, when I put the whole array in the inArray, it won't work. Like this:

`in_array($firstArray, $secondArray)`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You state: *"Something like this in_array($firstArray[0], $secondArray) works."* --- But then state: *"However, when I put the whole array in the inArray, it won't work. Like this:

in_array($firstArray[0], $secondArray)"* - There's something I'm not grasping and there's something you're probably not showing us/telling us and that would be the query itself and/or the value of the arrays. Edit: This comment was based on the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46333586/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, i updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/array_intersect) if you want to know if they intersect, you can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to see if the two arrays have any differences.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 && !array_diff($firstArray, $secondArray)){
       exit("exiting now!");
} else {
       echo "continue to do stuff...";
}
```

Example:

```
<?php
$array1 = array (1,2,3,4);
$array2 = array (3,2,1,5);
$array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$array4 = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
echo "<pre>";
echo "Array 1\n ";
print_r($array1);
echo "Array 2\n ";
print_r($array2);

echo "Arrays Difference \n ";
print_r($array3);
echo "Arrays intersect \n ";
print_r($array4);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
Array 1
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array 2
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
Arrays Difference 
 Array
(
    [3] => 4
)
Arrays intersect 
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Does it return a boolean true or false that can be used in my conditional?

Comment: Did you click on the links? It gives proper example. You can use `if (array_diff($blah, $lbah))`

Comment: The return value is not a boolean.

Comment: Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays. So in order to use it in a conditional i will need to create my own function right?

Comment: In PHP, an empty array evaluates to false. so `!array_diff` means they have the same content. [Booleans in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Thank you, so is `array_intersect` and `!array_diff` technically the same thing?

Comment: Update the answer with example for difference between the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for array_intersect() which returns the values that are common in two (or more) arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

It returns an array but if it returns an empty array then empty arrays are falsy.

Comment: Does it return a boolean true or false that can be used in my conditional?